# What Excel function finds values from col A that are not in col B, and vice versa?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to extract in a new column, the difference between two other columns, for example:

```
COLUMN A    COLUMN B
--------    --------
A7901RXW    A7901RKH
A7901RXX    A7901RKI
A7901RY3    A7901RXW
A7901RY4    A7901RXX
A7901R4V    A7901RY3
A7901R4V    A7901RY4
A7901R4V    A7901R4V
A7901S25    A7901R4V
A7901YQB    A7901R4V
A7901YQD    A7901S25
A7901YQ7    A7901S3Z
A7902AD0    A7901S3Z
A7902A0V    A7901YQB
A7902A0V    A7901YQD
A7902A1E    A7901YQ7
```

Any idea to reconigze easily which cells values we can find in column A but not in column B and vice versa?

In the example:

```
A7901RKH
A7901RKI
A7901S3Z
A7901S3Z
ect...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `VLOOKUP` function. Check out the following pages to learn how to use it: [[1]](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx),[[2]](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php),[[3]](http://www.timeatlas.com/5_minute_tips/general/learning_vlookup_in_excel).

Note: Good examples are given on the above pages.